# Test if a package option defined through pgf is empty

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfkeys, package-writing, pgfopts

I would like to branch on package/class options defined through the `pgfopts` package. Here is an example :

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/01]
\LoadClass{article}

% Packages
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

% Pgfoptions
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    myoption/.store in = \myoption,
    myoption =,
    optionA/.code = \def\myoption{optionA},
    optionA/.value forbidden
    optionB/.code = \def\myoption{optionB},
    optionB/.value forbidden
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

% Trying to branch on myoption (but not working)
\if\relax\detokenize{\myoption}\relax
    \newcommand{\printmyoption}{\texttt{myoption = NOT DEFINED}}
\else
    \newcommand{\printmyoption}{\texttt{myoption = \myoption}}
\fi
```

---

The idea of the syntax is to be able to write:

```
\documentclass[optionA]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption % Should write "myoption = optionA"
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[myoption = optionB]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption % Should write "myoption = optionB"
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printmyoption % Should write "myoption = NOT DEFINED"
\end{document}
```

---

**QUESTION:** How to branch on whether one of the package/class option category has been defined? By what should I replace `\if\relax\detokenize{\myoption}\relax`

**BONUS QUESTION:** I need to use `pgfopts`, but let me know if there would be a far better way of handling categories of options with both the syntax `[myoption = optionX]` and directly `[optionX]`.

Comment: Why not initialize `\myoption` with something the user can't choose, i.e. something with `@` like `\myoptions@undefined` and test against that with `\ifx`? (I wouldn't use a macro but a value-key but it doesn't change anything.) Or just check whether `\myoptions` is actually defined.

Comment: Bonus question: `myoption/.is choice, myoption/optionA/.code=<stuff>, myoption/optionB/.code=<other stuff>` (user can access these with `myoption=optionA` and an undefined choice raises an error). Then you can do `optionA/.style={myoption/optionA}` or `.search also=/myclass/myoption`. But why two ways to set options anyway?

Comment: You also need at least `\detokenize\expandafter{\myoption}` (if it is defined), otherwise you're always getting the letters ``\``, `m`, `y`, … which means you just need it to initalize it with `{}` to test for empty/not set (unless the user does `myoption=`).